# How to ignore last newline in a multiline string with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sh

I need to turn `foo,bar` into

```
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar)
```

The `\` is there as-is.

I tried with `echo 'foo,bar' | tr , '\n' | perl -pe 's/(.*)\n/BAZ($1) \\\n/g'` but that produces

```
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar) \
```

So, this is either a totally wrong approach or I'd need a way to ignore the last newline in a multiline string with Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) to detect if you're on the last line:

```
echo 'foo,bar' | tr , '\n' | perl -pe 'my $break = (eof) ? "" : "\\"; s/(.*)\n/BAZ($1) $break\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for producing something that's so close to my original statement. It doesn't even need an explanation because it's easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `join` with `map`, like this:

```
$ echo 'foo,bar' | perl -F, -lape '$_ = join(" \\\n", map { "BAZ(" . $_ . ")" } @F)'
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar)
```

- `-a` enables auto-split mode, splitting the input using the `,` delimiter and assigning it to `@F`
- `map` takes every element of the array and wraps it
- `join` adds the backslash and newline between each element

Comment: Works well, nice explanations, thanks. I'm not versed enough in Perl to decide if this or @robearl's answer are "better". His answer is easier to grasp for Perl rookies like me.

Comment: No problem. I guess that one advantage to this approach is that `tr` isn't needed. Personally, I find the logic simpler too - less conditional behaviour is a good thing. It's up to you though! I guess that once you become more familiar with using `map` (recommended), it makes a lot more sense. The use of `-p` and assigning to `$_` saves a couple of characters but it's probably clearer to use `-n` and `print` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 'foo,bar' | perl -ne'print join " \\\n", map "BAZ($_)", /\w+/g'
```

**output**

```
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
s='foo,bar'
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "BAZ(%s) %s\n", $i, (i<NF)? "\\" : ""}' <<< "$s"
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar)
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]+)$/BAZ(\1)/; s/([^,]+),/BAZ(\1) \\\n/g' <<< "$s"
BAZ(foo) \
BAZ(bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `sed` alternative. The `-r` flag doesn't work on OS X, the regexp would have to be re-phrased.

Comment: On OSX it will be: `sed -E $'s/([^,]+)$/BAZ(\\1)/; s/([^,]+),/BAZ(\\1) \\\\\\\n/g <<< "$s"`